# How does one use SimpleDOM sortedXPath to sort on node value?

Tags: php, simpledom

XML newbie here!
I have a file containing only the following XML:

```
<tags>
 <tag>orange</tag>
 <tag>apple</tag>
 <tag>banana</tag>
</tags>
```

I want to ouput the tags alphabetically.
I am trying to use SimpleDOM library and its **sortedXPath** method. Here's what I have so far, which outputs the tags unsorted.

```
$allTags = simpledom_load_file("tags.xml");
foreach ($allTags->sortedXPath("//tags/tag", "tag") as $i => $item)
{
   echo($item);
}
```

Could someone tell me how to write this correctly so it works? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In XPath, you can refer the current node (called "context node") using a single dot `.` so if you're accessing `//tags/tag` you have to use `.` to get the value of `tag`. Your example becomes:

```
$allTags = simpledom_load_file("tags.xml");
foreach ($allTags->sortedXPath("//tags/tag", ".") as $i => $item)
{
    echo($item);
}
```